# Magento 2 Shipping method not working - "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time "

Tags: magento2, php, shipping, fedex

I have enabled Free Shipping Method and Fedex in Magento 2 but during checkout I get an error as shown below -

[image]

What might be the issue ?

Comment: Are you using any extension for shipping method?

Comment: No just the default Fedex method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to add code to this one file.

**pub/static/frontend/magento/theme/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address.js**

```
addressOptions.push(newAddressOption);

       // start adding fix
       if (_.isEmpty(countryData())) {
    countryData(customerData.reload(['directory-data'], false));
       }
       // end adding fix

return Component.extend({
```

you need to copy code in your Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address.js extension file in also so once you deploy it will not delete.

Comment: This worked for us. Thanks, how on earth did you uncover this bug!?

Comment: It's my job to recognize issues.

Comment: I have changed in this billing-address.js file, but I cannot see the change in the browser. I have tried every option. Can you please tell me what more to do to see the change?

Comment: For anyone else, if the fix doesn't work patching the theme static files, try patching the core file and re-deploying the static files. If that still doesn't fix it, ensure all caches, including browser are cleared and log the customer account out/in.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the web services url was blocked in my office. I went home and carried out the process from different network and Voila ! It worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select state for US. Each shipping method registers fields which change may mean it is available/unavailable and default ones are listening on country, region_id/region and postcode. Changing one of it tries to refresh shipping methods but in order to do that all observerd fields need to be valid. Since region_id is required for US no refresh on shipping methods is done.

Comment: Even after selecting state, city, zipcode for US the error remains same. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: I figured out that the web services url was blocked in my office. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I spent a little time on this issue and found that the PHP Soap extension was not installed. Check your developer console and requests to estimate-shipping-methods to see if there is an error upon input changes.